# Attaching existing Database into the application during instllation: Setup Project

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, installation, custom-action, setup-deployment

I have a C# windows application running in Visual studio 2013 for which I have created an installer using setup and deployment. For this application I am using MySQL database as a separate entity which has Table creation script, Stored procedure and a database batch file to run all the scripts.

But Now I have a requirement to send this database candidate into the installer.
Tried few options like running the database batch file in the custom action after commit, which didn't go well. If I don't want to use batch file execution method(Because none of the options executing the batch file at the end of the installation worked for me) how can I attach this existing database to my setup project at the commit time?

I am handling connections in the application code taking connection string from appconfig.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CRSDatabaseString" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=Tel_CRS; Uid=root; Pwd=root123; Persistsecurityinfo=True;" />
    <add name="CSSDatabaseString" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=Tel_css; Uid=root; Pwd=root123; Persistsecurityinfo=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And the SQL connection in the application code as follows:

```
public  MySQL_Connection()
        {
                         String conn ="";
            if (Bootstrapper.InspectionTarget=="css")
                 conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CSSDatabaseString"].ConnectionString;
            else
                conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRSDatabaseString"].ConnectionString;


            Db_conn = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            Db_conn.Open();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this might not work in a Visual Studio custom action. The most common is that custom actions run with the system account (so that they are elevated) in a Everyone (per machine) install, and databases typically don't allow access to the system account. Another might be that the DB is on a network, but the system account has no network access privileges.

It's not clear if your code is running from an executable or an installer class Dll, but either way the code is not being run in the same context as it would be run from the Windows shell on behalf of the interactive user: there is no default working directory (you are running from an msiexec.exe process); access to user profile locations will fail (the system account has no desktop folder, for example) and in an installer class Dll the configuration/settings files aren't available in the usual way because installer classes are instantiated with reflection, not in the usual assembly load way. In other words, just because the code runs when you test it as an interactive user doesn't mean it will work when running with the system account and run from an msiexec.exe process.

It might be better to get this done when the user first tries to use the app (and NOT from the install) especially if you already have code to do this. Then it will run in a normal user context and can easily be retried if it fails, which might not the case if it fails during installation.

Comment: The above SQL Connection code is from an application exe, but all the logic to run the SQL scripts is in installer class. In your last paragraph do you mean to have the installer class to run ONBEFOREINSTALLATION()? But for now I have added the SQL connection code in the Installer class too.

Comment: Visual Studio custom actions all run after all the files have been installed, so "before install" is a very misleading description of what happens. Also, you didn't say anything about the errors that connecting to the DB returned, but if you get errors about the user not allowed access then it's most likely because installer class code runs with the system account in an Everyone install, as I said.